# Knockout bind nested collections

Tags: knockout.js, collections

I have next ViewModel with **Questions** collection which contains **Answers** collection.
I tried to bind but only PoolText and elements of first collection- **Questions** look correct. Answers collection miss at all.
Actually in the example is Javasctip model that need to be mapped. My viewmodel is like this:

```
function VM(){
  this.PoolText = ko.observabe();
  this.Qusetions = ko.observableArray([]);
  this.Qusetions.Answers = ko.observableArray([]);//is this correct???
} 

function Question(){
 this.ID = ko.observabe();
 this.QuestionText = ko.observabe();
 this.Answers = ko.observableArray([]);
}

function Answer(){
 this.AnswerText = ko.observabe();
 this.Points = ko.observabe();
}
```

```js
var vm = {
  "ID": 1,
  "PoolText": "Pool1",
  "Questions": [{
    "ID": 2,
    "QuestionText": "Q1",
    "Answers": [{
      "ID": 3,
      "AnswerText": "A1",
      "Points": 1.00
    }, {
      "ID": 4,
      "AnswerText": "A2",
      "Points": 1.00
    }, {
      "ID": 5,
      "AnswerText": "A3",
      "Points": 1.00
    }]
  }, {
    "ID": 3,
    "QuestionText": "Q2",
    "Answers": [{
      "ID": 7,
      "AnswerText": "AA1",
      "Points": 1.00
    }, {
      "ID": 8,
      "AnswerText": "AA2",
      "Points": 1.00
    }, {
      "ID": 9,
      "AnswerText": "AA3",
      "Points": 1.00
    }]
  }, {
    "ID": 4,
    "QuestionText": "Q3",
    "Answers": []
  }]
}
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="text: PoolText"></div>
<ul data-bind="foreach: Questions">
  <li data-bind="text: QuestionText">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: Answers">
      <li data-bind="text: AnswerText"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your HTML structure. You have a following structure for your inner items:

```
<li data-bind="text: QuestionText">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: Answers">
       <li data-bind="text: AnswerText"></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

You use `text` binding on your outer tag, so everything that is inside this tag is overwritten with result from this binding. This means that inner `foreach` is never executed, because it is overwritten. In order to fix that you need to separate the first binding from `li` tag, for example like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: Questions">
    <li>
        <span  data-bind="text: QuestionText" ></span>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: Answers">
            <li data-bind="text: AnswerText"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```